# Laravel Connection with docker mysql

Tags: mysql, laravel, docker

I am connecting my Laravel application with `docker-composer.yml`

I pull MySQL image and PHPMyAdmin image through CLI and connect MySQL and PHPMyAdmin in a container in the same network and I am trying to connect my Laravel application in localhost.

**Laravel ENV:**

```
'DB_CONNECTION=mysql'
'DB_HOST=mysql'
'DB_PORT=3306'
'DB_DATABASE=select_elect'
'DB_USERNAME=root
'DB_PASSWORD=root'
```

**Container Info:**

[image]

**Error:**

```
php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known.
```

Please guide me where I am doing a mistake.

Comment: Could you share the docker-compose file?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to connect not from a container, but from a host - then you need to add docker-compose for MySQL service first:

```
ports:
  - "3306:3306"
```

e.g.

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  db:
    restart: unless-stopped
    image: mysql:latest
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
```

CLI:

```
docker run -p 3306:3306 mysql:latest
```

This will make the MySQL service and port accessible from outside the docker network.

But if you trying to connect from inside same docker network, check if your service has a name `mysql`, because you use values: `'DB_HOST=mysql'`

Comment: Thanks for your reply it's working fine now